# Estimating a first order plus dead time model

Tags: regression, time-series, model-selection

The data generating process is given by the following differential equation:
$y(t) = a + b u(t - \theta) + c \frac {dy} {dt}$
Now imagine having as data a long time series for both $y$ and $u$.

If $\theta$ is known, this is an easy linear regression. But is there a "correct" procedure when the delay $\theta$ is unknown?
Right now I treat it as a model-selection problem, running multiple regressions and choosing the one that predicts with the smallest error. That is clunky though, so if a better method exists, great!

To clarify:

- $u(\cdot)$ is a function. It is an arbitrary stream of inputs
- $a$,$b$,$c$ and $\theta$ are parameters. Fixed and unknown.
- You can assume a gaussian $\epsilon$ measurement error whenever $y(t)$ is observed.
- The only data I have is a long series of daily observations of the pair $(u,y)$, where $u$ is observed perfectly.
- I feed $y_{t}-y_{t-1}$ for the derivative, which is appropriate since the original model is really a difference equation.

Comment: Could you clarify the ambiguous notation? The other information in this suggests, without actually saying so, that (1) $u$ denotes a function rather than a constant; (2) $t-\theta$ is its argument rather than a multiplicative factor; and (3) $a$, $b$, $c$, and $\theta$ are fixed (but unknown) parameters to be estimated from a *bivariate* time series $(U(t_i), Y(t_i)), i=1, 2, \ldots$ where the $(U,Y)$ are assumed to differ from the (unknown) $(u,y)$ by some kind of zero-mean random process. (What are the assumptions about that process?)

Comment: Thank you! There are some subtle issues lurking. You seem to imply that $u$ is observed without error: that is potentially an important assumption. Another is that somehow you will have to estimate $dy/dt$, presumably from the observations of $y$: but those observations have errors. Your estimate of $dy/dt$ will not only have an error that is multiplied by the unknown $c$, but its error will also be correlated with the error in $y$. That's no "easy linear regression"!

Comment: Is the derivative in the third term based on the observed-with-error-y(t) or the unobserved-(and without error)-y(t)?

Comment: the derivative is generated as y(t)-y(t-1). I clarified. u(t) is observed perfectly (it is user generated after all). Whuber thanks for the comment, but what's the problem of treating this as just an AR1?