# How to deal with bouts of equilibrium in an online learning setting?

Tags: regression, model-selection, kalman-filter, online-algorithms, overfitting

I have a kalman filter (a recursive least square filter, really) regressing over real-time streams of data. Because the data-generating process varies slightly over time I add an exponential forgetting factor to the kalman filter.
It all fits nicely with good prediction.

The problem I have is that the variables in input streams sometimes enter long periods of equilibrium. In those periods of time all I receive in the input streams are the same $y_t$ and same $x_t$ (except for background white noise). If the equilibrium remains for long enough the kalman fit starts degrading as it forgets old useful data and gives more and more importance to the background noise in equilibrium.

What I'd like to know is if there is any method to avoid overfitting the filter to useless new data. Right now I am using very ad-hoc methods (tallying a moving standard deviation to use as weight in the regression), but there must be better way to regularize a regression in an online setting.

Comment: Is this about fitting time varying regression coefficients for $y_t = \alpha + \beta\,x_t$? and you observe $\alpha,~\beta$? Can you explain the details of your model  (I'm not sure why you need a "exponential forgetting factor" instead of just the process noise in the KF, which leads me to suspect I have misunderstood something).   An example (e.g. a plot of the inputs and the state estimates) of the phenomenon in question could also be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if cross-validation in online setting can be useful

Kohn, Ansley A Fast Algorithm for Signal Extraction, Influence and Cross-Validation in State Space Models. Biometrika, Vol. 76, No. 1

Piet De Jong A Cross-Validation Filter for Time Series Models. Biometrika, Vol. 75, No. 3 (Sep., 1988), pp. 594-600

Comment: useful ideas. Still have to see if I am able to implement them, but thanks a lot!

Comment: Honestly, I did not think this through, so I'd be interested to know how it played out. Good luck!

Comment: For some weird reasons the references ended up helping me out in another question of mine: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/105201/6793.  
For this question I am honestly still keeping a moving variance of the last observations and stop regressing whenever that variance drops to 0 (which is equilibrium). It's ugly, but it gets the job done.

Comment: +1 I recommand the first reference. Despite of some minor typos in the algorithm as written, it works fine for many problems.